# FQL select column name "AS" alias

Tags: javascript, facebook, select, facebook-fql, alias

I am using JSDK, but the problem is for sure in FQL request.

I am trying select which makes basic operation and i want to name the result. But facebook always name it "anon"

SQL example:

```
SELECT (register_time - unregister_time) AS time_registered FROM users where id='1';
```

It is all about keyword AS.

FQL with problem:

```
SELECT 1 + 2  from user where uid=me();
```

It works, but result 3 will have name anon. But I want something like this:

```
SELECT 1 + 2 AS result  from user where uid=me();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't know "AS".

Of course I can get value from "anon". But it is quite unhandy when there is more these values.

Is there any way how to name it?

Comment: So far as I can tell, you can't.  In fact, it doesn't seem that you're able to SELECT more than 1 anonymous field at a time either.

Comment: Actually, when i was trying i was able.

Comment: What was your query and where/how did you run it?  The following, when run in the Graph API Explorer tool only returns a single "anon" field with value 1:

SELECT 1,2 FROM user WHERE uid = me()

Comment: I tried it in developer console. But in real aplication it will look like there is just 1 anonymous field, because of the same name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Currently facebook FQL doesn't supports `select column name "AS" alias`.** We all love to have to this feature. It's really unhandy to access such instances.

So we have to wait for some time.